# Drizzle-kit Error: TypeError: obj.enumValues.reduce is not a function

Tags: next.js, drizzle

I am using Drizzle-ORM to manage my database tables, specifically using drizzle-kit push:pg.

The error message suggests that there's a problem with the enumValues property of an object in the Drizzle Kit codebase. Specifically, it seems that this property is expected to be an array, but it's not recognized as such, leading to a TypeError when attempting to call the reduce function on it.

What's causing this and is there a workaround? I've already made sure the drizzle-kit package is up to date.

```
 npx drizzle-kit push:pg
drizzle-kit: v0.20.14
drizzle-orm: v0.29.3

No config path provided, using default path
Reading config file 'C:\Users\drizzle.config.ts'
TypeError: obj.enumValues.reduce is not a function
    at C:\Users\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:12386:42
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at generatePgSnapshot (C:\Users\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:12384:35)      
    at serializePg (C:\Users\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:13311:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async preparePgDbPushSnapshot (C:\Users\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:13380:26)
    at async preparePgPush (C:\Users\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:14907:31)     
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:63197:22)
```

Comment: checked my drizzle.config.ts and schema.ts files for errors and have found none